# maven-jarsigner-plugin vs maven-jar-plugin

Tags: android, maven, maven-jar-plugin

What is difference between maven-jarsigner-plugin and maven-jar-plugin?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/

In android, I use maven-jarsigner-plugin.today seeing another android project, parent POM uses a  plugin named maven-jar-plugin.

1 I want to know their diff, and show a simple example

2 in android, which one is prefered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven-jarsigner-plugin intention is, excerpt from the docs:

> This plugin provides the capability to sign or verify a project
>   artifact and attachments using jarsigner.

whereas the maven-jar-plugin is intention is to create jar files.